# EXCEL, Bloomberg : How to get CDS ticker from the equity ticker

Tags: excel, bloomberg, ticker, cds

My problem is : I downloaded on EXCEL all the members of an index and I added "Equity" to get the ticker of the equity but I cannot get the ticker of the CDS. 
I succeed to got the BB number of each cds (6M, 1Y, 2Y, 5Y, 10Y etc..). 
But from that, I cannot get the Full name. For instance for the french bank BNP paribas : Full name is BNP CDS EUR SR 5Y D14 and bb Number is CBNPE5.
I have tried to download CDS price with tickers like NAME_CORP & "CDS EUR..". But it only works for few companies.
Does someone have a solution ?

My goal is to be able from the equity ticker of a company to download with BDH and "px_last" the prices of the CDSs in the last two or five years.

I hope that my problem is clear and I thank you for your help.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the Bloomberg service: the right way to do it is to find the cds ticker with BDP and the field "CDS_SPREAD_TICkER_5T") and then use the result (called RES) with BDP (RES & "Curncy","px_last").

Answer (score 0):

Put the Equity ticker in A1, say `BNP FP Equity`.

Put the formula below in A2 to retrieve the 5Y CDS ticker:

```
=BDP(A1, "CDS_SPREAD_TICKER_5Y")
```

Then use this formula to retrieve the price of the CDS:

```
=BDP(A2 & " Corp", "PX_LAST")
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works for most of the cases. 
When I got "#N/A N/A" for instance for Barclays "BARC LN Equity" or Capgemini "CAP FP Equity" does it mean that I cannot download the price ? Because when I am trying for other periods than 5Y a lot of cells display this message.

Comment: It only works for most of the cases with 5Y. Furthermore, sometimes it said NA when with others methods such as writing "CDS EUR SR 10Y D14 Corp" after the first letters of the ticker of the equity give me a price. I am looking for a global method which always works when data is available...

Comment: I see - have you asked HELP HELP why `=BDP("CCAP1E5 Curncy","PX LAST")` doesn't work (the CDS ticker for Capgemini)?

Comment: Yeah using "Curncy" instead of "Corp" was the right answer. And if there are some "NA", it's probably because the information are not free.